# Can't figure out how to install ViewPager

Tags: android

For the past hour, I've been looking at how to add support libraries to your build path so that I can learn how to use ViewPager. But for some reason, after I add the jars to my build path and clean the project, nothing new shows up in my palette and if I try to copy and past some XML code for a ViewPager in, it doesn't recognize it in the build path! I really have no idea what's going wrong here. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post any screenshot or something? It'll be easier for everyone to help you fix the issue.

Anyway you will need to add android-support-v4.jar to use ViewPager. Usually when you add this jar to libs folder and build path, then you can add code to your xml file just like this (it also didn't show up in my palette):

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.test.MainActivity" />
```

There's an easy way to check your issue.

- Create a new Android application in Eclipse/Android Studio
- When it asks you to create a activity or not, choose Tabbed Activity and then choose ViewPager in Navigation Style combo-box
- Once the project is successfully compiled, customize it the way you want or compare it to your own project to check if you're missing something. Good luck!